# docusign error calling webservice, status is:401

Tags: php, web-services, curl, docusignapi

i get this error calling webservice, status is:401 when i made a new account a member account (non developer account and try to integrate it in a form that i have..i based the code from the api walkthroughs in docusign itself

```
<?php
if(($_POST['submit']))
{
// Input your info here:
$integratorKey = 'XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX';
$email = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
$email1 = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$email2 = 'XXXXXXXX';
$password = 'XXXXXXXX';
$name = 'XXX';
$name2 = 'XXXXXX';

// construct the authentication header:
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 1 - Login (to retrieve baseUrl and accountId)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);

//--- display results


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    //////
// STEP 2 - Create an envelope with one recipient, one tab, one document and send!
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    //////
$data = "{
\"emailBlurb\":\"This comes from Dateguard\",
\"emailSubject\":\"DocuSign API - Please Sign This Contract for Dateguard...\",
\"documents\":[
{
\"documentId\":\"1\",
\"name\":\"contract.pdf\"
}
],
\"recipients\":{
\"signers\":[
{
\"email\":\"$email1\",
\"name\":\"$name\",
\"recipientId\":\"1\",
\"tabs\":{
\"signHereTabs\":[
{
\"xPosition\":\"80\",
\"yPosition\":\"550\",
\"documentId\":\"1\",
\"pageNumber\":\"1\"
}
]
}
},
{
\"email\":\"$email2\",
\"name\":\"$name2\",
\"recipientId\":\"2\",
\"tabs\":{





\"signHereTabs\":[
{
\"xPosition\":\"400\",
\"yPosition\":\"550\",
\"documentId\":\"1\",
\"pageNumber\":\"1\"
}
]
}   
}





 ]
 },
 \"status\":\"sent\"
}";

 $file_contents = file_get_contents("contract.pdf");

$requestBody = "\r\n"
."\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n"
."\r\n"
."$data\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type:application/pdf\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"contract.pdf\"; documentid=1 \r\n"
."\r\n"
."$file_contents\r\n"
."--myboundary--\r\n"
."\r\n";

// *** append "/envelopes" to baseUrl and as signature request endpoint
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=myboundary',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($requestBody),
"X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];

//--- display results
    $home_url = 'thanks.php';
    header('Location: ' . $home_url);   

}



?>
```

now the problem is when i use my developer account in docusign as credentials for the api it works but when i create a member account it does not( the free trial )..is it supposed to work that way?am i missing something? if it is then how am i supposed to use the api to work so that a member use their own account and use their own credentials and be able to use it in docusign api and not my own developer account because of the "test" indication. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is not enabled on DocuSign free-trial accounts - it's enabled on free developer sandbox accounts (which do NOT expire after 30 days).  The only way to create those accounts are through the [DocuSign Developer Center](http://www.docusign.com/devcenter) .

Of course, if you have a live integration, meaning you passed Certification with DocuSign, then you might have a production account which has the api enabled, but while you are developing and testing you can only do so with developer accounts and not the free trials.

Comment: i see..is that really how it is then? you mean i cant have each and everyone of the users create their own account in docusign? so that the contract would say that it came from them? and can i ask how do you pass certification for docusign?

Comment: You can add multiple users through the api or through the Console to your developer account if you want to test with multiple users.  Regarding Certification, please see the `Go Live` section of the DocuSign Developer Center:  www.docusign.com/devcenter

Answer (score 1):

> 401 Authorization Required

If the code is good with developer account, then the reason should be the account privilege.

Comment: yeah thats what i read about it but all the permissions for the account are all checked at least all the relevant info meaning except powerforms transaction point and evault in the lower part..and some are initially checked and some blurred and not initially checked..namely Signer Attachments    
Signing on Paper Override